# How do you add a new column in R and assign specific values to specific rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have an existing dataframe e.g.:

| Sample | Source | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5-SC | Uintas | x | y |
| 5-SC | SM | x | y |
| 5-SC | CMB | x | y |
| 5-SC | Uintas | x | y |
| 5-SC | SM | x | y |
| 5-SC | CMB | x | y |

I'd like to add a column after "Sample" wherein i assign specific values to specific rows e.g.:

| Sample | Metric | Source | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5-SC | CC | Uintas | x | y |
| 5-SC | CC | SM | x | y |
| 5-SC | KV | Uintas | x | y |
| 5-SC | KV | SM | x | y |
| 5-SC | KSD | Uintas | x | y |
| 5-SC | KSD | SM | x | y |

This is my failing effort so far:

```
data <- add_column(data, Metric = (CC %in% c(1:2), KV %in% c(3:4), KSD %in% c(5:6)),.after = 'Sample_ID')
```

Please forgive the simplicity of this question, but i simply can't figure it out no matter how i Google things or sift through SO.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  add_column(Metric = rep(c('CC', 'KV', 'KSD'), each = 2), .after = 'Sample')

 Sample Metric Source X1 X2
1   5-SC     CC Uintas  x  y
2   5-SC     CC     SM  x  y
3   5-SC     KV    CMB  x  y
4   5-SC     KV Uintas  x  y
5   5-SC    KSD     SM  x  y
6   5-SC    KSD    CMB  x  y
```

Comment: Oh I never knew this function! I think you could also mention the library :)

Answer (score 1):

Base R option

```
df$Metric = rep(c('CC', 'KV', 'KSD'), each = 2)
df <- df[, c(1, 5, 2:4)]
```

Output

```
  Sample Metric Source X1 X2
1   5-SC     CC Uintas  x  y
2   5-SC     CC     SM  x  y
3   5-SC     KV    CMB  x  y
4   5-SC     KV Uintas  x  y
5   5-SC    KSD     SM  x  y
6   5-SC    KSD    CMB  x  y
```

Data

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    Sample = c("5-SC", "5-SC", "5-SC", "5-SC", "5-SC",
               "5-SC"),
    Source = c("Uintas", "SM", "CMB", "Uintas", "SM", "CMB"),
    X1 = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"),
    X2 = c("y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y")
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-6L)
)
```